# Отображаемые объекты в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Очень давно ищу и не могу найти не чего однозначного в отношении отображения кода в js.
Для меня было немного странным, что этот язык не имеет собственных классов рисования и когда я начал узнавать, как же всё таки отображать код, то точно так же не чего однозначного не получил. Кто говорил о Canvas, кто следующим постом говорил о его медленной работе. И после недели поисков у меня сложилось впечатлении, что это какая то тайна.
Может кто нибудь опровергнуть мои слова по поводу жадности на секреты js-кодеров и рассказать, что используете Вы для отображения и отображения\рисования анимации и интерактивной графики?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выбирайте:

- http://svgjs.com/
- http://raphaeljs.com/
- http://libcanvas.github.io/
- http://paperjs.org/
- http://processingjs.org/
- http://fabricjs.com/
- http://kineticjs.com/

Comment: @RubaXa: Спасибо! Но не могли бы Вы немного рассказать что это такое?
Точнее вот в чем дело - я в большей степени из всех языков знаю as3 и как Вы наверное знаете, там для рисования есть два класса - Graphics и Bitmap. И так же Вы наверняка знаете, что в as3 если нужно что то нарисовать, то рисуют кодом сами, без использования нативных классов.
И вот из такой информации - что мне больше подойдет из предложенного Вами? А то окажется, что эти фреймворки могут нарисовать квадрат со скругленными углами, да не той кривой как надо и без возможности анимирования. Или они все все могут?

Comment: Всё выше перечисленное предназначено для создания сложных фигур, анимаций и игр + дать удобный интерфейс для работы с canvas/svg. Если вам нужно что-то простое, то смотрите в сторону http://daneden.me/animate/

Comment: вы демки посмотрите на каждом сайте есть. или вот например http://media.tojicode.com/q3bsp/ что люди делают когда другие ноют.

Comment: Естественно я посмотрел и искренне восхитился, просто я уточнил, что если собирать не игру а сайт и для мультиплатформенности использовать jQuery, то не эти фраймворки не окажутся лишними. Вот я что имел ввиду. @eicto: а Вы хватаете все что Вам суют? Или ноете? И ещё Вы наверное php-ст? Они все нервные почему то...

Comment: почти все эти фреймворки совместимы с jQuery, я вообще сисадмин по основному профилю, и я не хватаю всё что мне суют, мне вообще ничего не суют. вот вам подсунули.

Comment: я пока ходил кормил кота... знаете что подумал? Что Вы либо php-ст, либо сисадмин.))) Вы просто устали наверное от чёрных\синих экранов и для Вас пример по Вашей ссылки, является чем то сногсшибательным.

Comment: И перестаньте писать когда курите. Прочитайте свои слова как отпустит
А причём софт? Может хватит ерунду говорить? Если Вам скучно, поищите в поиске порносайт...Хотя он тоже будет в "ненавистном флеш плеере".
Я ещё раз говорю - хватит говорить ерунду! Все разработчики флеш приложений создают iприложения на iсистемах.

Comment: так как насчет нормально работающего приложения без софта от adobe на flash (gnash,lightspark) ? Кстати без шуток,http://sap-consalt.ru/2011/07/10/porno-radi-html5-ili-html5-radi-porno/


не надо за всех, вы вообще к программированию мало отношения имеете.

Comment: цитата с сайта:

> Настал момент, когда технология начала ограничивать потребности людей. И главную из потребностей - смотреть порно. Если учесть что большинство порно сайтов использует для трансляции видео технологию Flash, то пользователи iДевайсов ограничены лишь просмотром картинок. Но ушлые разработчики никогда не стоят на месте, стандарт HTML5 позволяет использовать видео на ваших проектах без использования технологии Flash

Answer (score 1):

может не Ваш случай , но думаю большинство задач можо решить с помощью jquery & css (transform perspective и прочее)

Comment: А при использовании связки jquery с css можно рисовать всё что угодно? Для примера, если бы я решил создать игру или сложную анимацию, то мой взор упал бы на Canvas, так как он использует GPU.
Ну а если нужно просто нарисовать круг и сделать его перетаскиваемым или анимированную кнопку, фон какой нибудь текстурный - то что тогда использовать?

Comment: для перетаскивания можно подключить jquery ui 
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/
для анимированной кнопки для сложной анимации jQuery.animate
для простой
jQuery('#idelement').on('mouseenter',function(){ jQuery(this).addClass('hovered'});
где в классе hovered скажем другой фон или плавная смена фона через css transitions

Comment: canvas анимация руками - не такая уж простая задачка, нужно юзать софт а нормальный софт - платный

Comment: Чем больше я узнаю о js, тем больше задаюсь вопросом - Почему флеш хоронят? И получается, нарисовать круг -  jQuery, сделать фон css, поменять цвет фона css, а поменять цвет круга, опять jQuery.Остаётся только надеяться, что события jQuery как то можно передать в css. Можно же? А какой платный? Тот же Flash CC?

Comment: @shatal потому что флэш проприетарный и требует сторонних плагинов. **туда ему и дорога**

Comment: Каких сторонних плагинов? А html5 он как, по воле всевышнего показывает? Или тоже нужен современный браузер с его поддержкой? Или все что показывает браузер это не плагины?

Comment: **все что показывает браузер это не плагины** истино говорю вам, не плагины а программы. Вы вообще не шарите, зависли в своем флэше... ещё удивляется чего его хоронят, 

*хоронили флэш порвали три сильверлайта*

Comment: То есть устанавливать дополнительно программы лучше чем плагин?
И кодя на as3 мне не приходится писать сто кодов, чтобы ЭТО БЫЛО МУЛЬТИПЛАТФОРМЛЕНО.
Вы какой то через чур дикий! я только учусь и мне не понятен Ваш опытный ... я не знаю как это назвать. И под linux я не хочу не чего делать. Мне не нужно это, я деньги хочу зарабатывать на современных системах, а не стараться для linux.
Я не знаю что такое ВЕНДОР...

Comment: да лучше, особенно если это свободный браузер, типа chromium или firefox. плагины тоже неплохо, если они **не проприетарные** вы знаете почему обижены ? потому что **ваш вендор вас кинул** , а изучали бы что нить посвободнее этого не произошло бы.

Comment: да ? запилите ка мне под debian **gnu** linux(без non-free) пожалуйста небольшую демку...

Comment: > И кодя на as3 мне не приходится писать сто кодов, чтобы ЭТО БЫЛО МУЛЬТИПЛАТФОРМЛЕНО.

LOL кодя на js/php/java/c(с оговорками)/perl/lisp и прочем вам тоже почти не придется париться о мультиплатформености.

вы в ересь впали вот что я вам скажу, и еще раз **ВАШ ВЕНДОР ВАС КИНУЛ** более того, по другому и быть не могло.